# Выборка полей при INNER JOIN

Tags: sql

Есть запрос к БД:

```
SELECT * FROM content
INNER JOIN users ON (content.user_id = users.id)
INNER JOIN categories ON (content.category_id = categories.id)
```

После этого получаю массив в PHP:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < mysqli_num_rows($result); $i++) {
    $row[] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
}
```

В шаблоне с помощью Smarty вывожу записи:

```
{foreach $row as $item}
    <h3><a href="content.php?id={$item.id}">{$item.title}</a></h3>
    <p class="date"><b>Дата добавления:</b> {$item.pubdate}</p>
    <p class="autor"><b>Опубликовано:</b> {$item.nickname}</p>
    <p class="category"><b>Теги:</b> {$item.category_name}</p>
    <div class="description">{$item.content}</div>
    <a href="content.php?id={$item.id}" class="btn btn-info">Подробнее...</a>
{/foreach}
```

Проблема в том, что элемент массива `{$item.id}` выбирается не нужный, т.е. элемент соответствует таблице `category_id` в таблице `category`, т.е. последнее значение `id`, которое я присоединяю к таблице с помощью `INNER JOIN`.

Как правильно написать запрос с `JOIN`-ами?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спс помогли алиасы к табличкам чтобы не было лишнего
Запрос получился такой

```
SELECT
c.id,
c.title,
c.content,
c.pubdate,
u.nickname AS user,
cat.category_name AS tag
FROM content AS c
INNER JOIN users AS u ON c.user_id = u.id
INNER JOIN categories AS cat ON c.category_id = cat.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Укажите конкретные поля в запросе, вместо `*`:

```
SELECT content.id, <все остальные нужные поля через запятую с указанием таблиц> FROM content
INNER JOIN users ON (content.user_id = users.id)
INNER JOIN categories ON (content.category_id = categories.id)
```